# Browser, safari/IE negative margin not working

Tags: browser, safari, position, margin, absolute

I have a problem with safari. I have searched for 6 hours straight for a fix, so exscuse me if my explanation is bad. So the thing is: I have added a hover effect on my thumbnails, it works in all browsers, but the thumbs are not placed correctly in safari and IE. 
I have tried to use:

```
    @media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0){
    img.a {
position: absolute;
top: -500;
z-index: 10;
}

   img.b {
position: absolute;
top: -500;
}
    }
```

But this works for webkit browser, meaning chrome as well.

The css I am currently using which works in chrome and firefox:

```
    img.a {
position: absolute;
top: -500;
margin-left: -115px;
    z-index: 10;
width: 230px;
height: 120px;
border: none;
}

   img.b {
position: absolute;
top: -500;
margin-left: -115px;
width: 230px;
height: 120px;
border: none;
}
```

If anyone has a solution it would really save my day :)

Here is the site if you need to inspect: www.janthorb.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get rid of the CSS

div#thumbnails {
  text-align:center;
}

and also get rid of your margin-left: -115px for your images and you will have something that works in both browswers.

Comment: Thanks you so much :) I've stared at the css way too long. Peace at last.

Answer (score 0):

You page code is a mess, no alignment. HTML structure is not reasonable, and cause CSS also is very not science. I rewrote your structure, you can reference.

```
.demo{ width:820px;margin:0 auto;}
.list{ margin-right:-20px; zoom:1;}
.list li{ float:left; width:230px; height:135px; margin:0 36px 25px 0; overflow:hidden; zoom:1;}
.link{ position:relative;width:228px; height:120px; display:block;border:thin dashed #1b1b1b; overflow:hidden;}
.link img{ position:absolute;top:0;left:0; }
.link .gray{ z-index:11;}
.link .hover{ z-index:10;}

<ul class="list">
    <li>
        <a class="link" href="#">
            <img class="gray" src="http://www.janthorb.com/thumb1_bw.jpg" alt="">
            <img class="hover" src="http://www.janthorb.com/thumb1.jpg" alt="">
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a class="link" href="#">
            <img class="gray" src="http://www.janthorb.com/thumb1_bw.jpg" alt="">
            <img class="hover" src="http://www.janthorb.com/thumb1.jpg" alt="">
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

[and demo is here](http://jsfiddle.net/6PHTN/)